# Postgresql 8.4 service not starting windows 7

Tags: windows-7, postgresql

Hi All i am not able to start Postgresql service from service manager in windows-7.
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

although pg_ctl is started in taskmanager

Comment: Well, look at the windows error logs (Event Viewer), and PostgreSQL's own logs in the `data/pg_log` directory. Did you change anything? Did you just install Pg (and if so why on earth would you install 8.4?) or is this an old install? If it's an old install, what changed recently?

Comment: 1) These are event logs
Waiting for server startup...
Timed out waiting for server startup

Windows detected your registry file is still in use by other applications or services. The file will be unloaded now. The applications or services that hold your registry file may not function properly afterwards.  

 DETAIL - 
 7 user registry handles leaked from \Registry\User\S-1-5-21-783636078-1858336979-3876531679-1033:

Comment: I have to install because that product needs 8.4, can't run with 9.2

Comment: ... and the PostgreSQL logs, from `data/pg_log`? (By default, `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\data\pg_log`). As for needing 8.4, you'd better start grumping a the vendor of whatever the product is (or tell me what it is so I can grump at them), as 8.4 is end-of-life and going to be unsupported.

Comment: I just found a weird solution.. may be its logical. that my host file missing localhost-->127.0.0.1 entry  under /system32/dirvers/etc/host .. when i did that and restarted. it worked